# Can this systems of equations be solved?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

There is a system of equations as follow:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}x\\ y\\ \end{matrix} \right] = \left[\begin{matrix}a& b\\b & c\\\end{matrix} \right]\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{x}\\ \frac{1}{y}\\ \end{matrix} \right]$$

Given $ \left[\begin{matrix}a& b\\b & c\\\end{matrix} \right]$, can this system of equations be solved for $x$ and $y$?

---

And how to solve the extended case?
$$\left[\begin{matrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots \\x_n \end{matrix} \right] =
 \left[\begin{matrix}a_{11}& a_{12} & \dots &a_{1n}\\a_{12} & a_{22} & \dots  &a_{2n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots \\a_{1n} & a_{2n} & \dots &a_{nn}\end{matrix} \right]\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{x_1}\\ \frac{1}{x_2}\\ \vdots \\ \frac{1}{x_n}\\ \end{matrix} \right]$$

Comment: What've you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This is basically asking for $\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}=x$ and $\frac{b}{x}+\frac{c}{y}=y$. From the first equation, $y=\frac{xb}{x^2-a}$. You can substitute this into the second equation to get: $$\frac{b}{x}+\frac{c(x^2-a)}{bx}=\frac{xb}{x^2-a}$$

This should be translatable into a polynomial. However, the smallest polynomial that you can multiply this by to remove all denominators is $bx(x^2-a)=bx^3-abx$. Doing this gives $$b^2(x^2-a)+c(x^2-a)^2=b^2x^2.$$

This results in a quartic polynomial, which is always solvable, though tedious. There's probably a shortcut that I'm missing, but at least this is a solvable problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!! And look at the extended case.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the polynomial degree is 2n, where nxn is the matrix. That would mean that it's not necessarily solvable, but there could be shortcuts like the one Claude Leibovici used.

Answer (score 2):

**After pie314271's answer**

The equation $$b^2(x^2-a)+c(x^2-a)^2=b^2x^2$$ reduces to $$a\left(a c- b^2\right)-2 a c x^2+c x^4=0$$ which is just a quadratic in $x^2$ and the solutions are given by $$x=\pm\sqrt{a\pm\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{c}}\,b}$$ So, the whole set of solutions is
$$\left\{x= -\sqrt{a-\frac{\sqrt{a} b}{\sqrt{c}}},y= \frac{\sqrt{c}
   \sqrt{a-\frac{\sqrt{a} b}{\sqrt{c}}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right\},\left\{x=
   \sqrt{a-\frac{\sqrt{a} b}{\sqrt{c}}},y= -\frac{\sqrt{c} \sqrt{a-\frac{\sqrt{a}
   b}{\sqrt{c}}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right\},\left\{x=-\sqrt{a+\frac{\sqrt{a}
   b}{\sqrt{c}}},y= -\frac{\sqrt{c} \sqrt{a+\frac{\sqrt{a}
   b}{\sqrt{c}}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right\},\left\{x= \sqrt{a+\frac{\sqrt{a}
   b}{\sqrt{c}}},y=\frac{\sqrt{c} \sqrt{a+\frac{\sqrt{a}
   b}{\sqrt{c}}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right\}$$